# Applications for the order of an element in a group G

Tags: group-theory, big-list

Can someone give me concrete applications for the order of an element in a group G?

I found a lot of properties/lemmas of it but no concrete applications.

Comment: The order of an element is such a basic concept that I'd be willing to bet you could  take basically any "concrete application" of group theory, and the order of an element is bound to pop up.

Comment: It can be used for Euler's totient theorem, for example. I imagine you wanted a ([tag:big-list]) tag?

Comment: It's like asking for a concrete application of the concept *"noun"*. It's a rather broad and unclear question.

Comment: This question could be asked about every new definition you encounter. I think it is better to do first several "concrete" examples yourself and study a bit more group theory. Then the answer comes automatically (Lagrange, Euler and more).

Answer (score 1):

[Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) says the order of a group is a multiple of the order of its subgroup. This directly implies the [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem)( full version of Fermat's little theorem). Now Euler's theorem is used in cryptography, specifically the [RSA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).

But believe me this is just the tip of the iceberg!

P.S. it would be more specific if you asked the application of a certain theorem concerning the order of a group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Even though my question is about the order of an element in a group G. Not about the order/cardinality of a group G

Comment: This is about the order of an element. The order of an element equals the order of the cyclic subgroup which is generated by that element, which divides the order of the group.

Comment: @AyoubRossi, sure, I will make some changes to my answer,